# Working with a pair in lists

Tags: python, list, numpy, dataframe

I extract two values with a statement from a dataframe via:

```
date = data_audit.loc[data_audit.Audit == audit) & data_audit.Meilenstein == phase1), 'Planned_Date']

division = data_audit.loc[(data_audit.Audit == audit) & (data_audit.Meilenstein == phase1), 'Ber']
```

After that extract, I transform these values...

```
x = date.tolist()
y = division.tolist()
```

.. and append it to a list

```
time.extend((x, y))
```

My result in pycharm is (after looping the .extend through some values):

```
[[100], [A], [200], [A], [100], [B]]
```

My first question: Why is the result not like:

```
[([100], [A]), ([200], [A]), ([100], [B])] ?
```

My second question: I want to calculate the average of all first items (the integers) and of all first items (the integers) per exec (exec=A, B)

Result would be: All: 133, 33 | A: 150 | B: 100

How can I access all values of the "first value" of the pair in my list [(firstvalue,secondvalue),(,)...]

For example:

```
time= np.round(np.mean(timeCleaned[ACCESS_ALL_"FIRST"_VALUES_IN_MY_LIST]), 2)
```

Thank you!

edit: Variable names.

Comment: `time.extend(zip(x, y))`

Comment: Note: both names (`date` and `exec`) are poorly chosen (`time` as well - but I don't see its definition). Also, do you really want the output to be `[([100], [A]), ([200], [A]), ([100], [B])]`? wouldn't make more sense for it to be `[(100, A), (200, A), (100, B)]`?

Comment: Thank you - names are just "anonymized". [(100, A), (200, A), (100, B)]? would make more sense. Append fixed the missing "()" problem, I think the "[]" problem comes from the "tolist()". with the tolist() i was able to add items extracted from a dataframe to my list

Comment: You should not use `exec` as a variable name! `exec` is a function of builtins module and thus should never be overloaded!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`extend` unpacks and appends each item of an iterable to your list. Use `append` instead:

```
time.append((x, y))
```